# How do I some the error message; Unable to resolve module Expo App?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to make an app with react native using an expo project with the typescript blank template. I am also trying to write the code for my api server. I have some model objects and interfaces that I use both on the server side and on the client side. I have decided to make my directory this way.

```
Programming/
client/<this is where I created the expo project>
server/<this is where I have the server files>
shared/model/<this is where I have some interfaces, and model files>
```

From within the client folder, I have some tsx files where I use import statement to refer to the files inside the shared folder. When I launch the app, I get this error message:

```
`Unable to resolve module ../../../shared/model/types from /home/user/desktop/programming/client/app/stores/authStore.tsx.`
```

I used the autocomplete vs code feature to put the path of the file. So I know that it is the correct path. Here is the import statement:
`import { AccessToken, AuthError } from "../../../shared/model/types";`

When I copy the content of the file and put it inside the same client directory within the same folder where the authStore.tsx and use:

```
'./types'
```

in the import statement, it works fine. I find it annoying that I have to have 2 similar copies of the files, one for the server and one for the client. I would like to refer to the same file from both projects.

I tried to ask chat gpt for a solution. It could not help.

Comment: I think the problem is that you react app cannot access a file outside its own directory. Maybe take a look to this article https://dushyant37.medium.com/how-to-import-files-from-outside-of-root-directory-with-react-native-metro-bundler-18207a348427